# How to change order of two columns?

Tags: multicol

Is it possible in two columns page style, change order of column 1 and column 2?
In other words I want to have a latex page as follow:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What is meant by changing the order?  Should the right-hand column fill up with text first?  Should the columns be automatically balanced?

Comment: Yes,  right-hand column fill up with text first. I want to change place of left column by right column.

Comment: Is this question about when using columns from the [`multicol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package or using the `twocolumn` class options/`\twocolumn` macro?

Comment: I used multicol package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To switch between typesetting columns from left to right and right to left, the [`multicol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package provides the `\RLmulticolcolumns` and `\LRmulticolcolumns` commands which reverse the order in which columns are produced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\RLmulticolcolumns
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `columns` environment for ConTeXt let you change the order of the columns with the `direction` key.

```
\setupcolumns
  [direction=left]

\starttext

\startcolumns
The Earth, as a habitat for animal life, is in old age and
has a fatal illness. Several, in fact. It would be happening
whether humans had ever evolved or not. But our presence is
like the effect of an old-age patient who smokes many packs
of cigarettes per day – and we humans are the cigarettes.
\stopcolumns

\stoptext
```

[image]

When the newer `mixedcolumns` environment is used one has to use the `reverse` keyword for the `direction` key.

```
\setupmixedcolumns
  [align=verytolerant,
   balance=yes,
   direction=reverse]

\starttext

\startmixedcolumns
The Earth, as a habitat for animal life, is in old age and
has a fatal illness. Several, in fact. It would be happening
whether humans had ever evolved or not. But our presence is
like the effect of an old-age patient who smokes many packs
of cigarettes per day – and we humans are the cigarettes.
\stopmixedcolumns

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a general answer but is useful. If we use [xepersian](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xepersian) package then we can use \RTLmulticolcolumns and \LTRmulticolcolumns commands which reverse the order.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{xepersian}
    \settextfont[Scale=1]{B Nazanin}.
    \setlatintextfont{Times New Roman}
    \setdigitfont[Scale=1]{Yas}
    \begin{document}

    \RTLmulticolcolumns
    \begin{multicols}{2}

    some persian tex

    \end{multicols}
    \LTRmulticolcolumns
    \begin{multicols}{2}

    some persian tex

    \end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: multicol already offers that out of the box for a couple of years.´so there is no need to load additional packages to achieve the effect

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: I am using xepersian to write a text contatining both RTL and LTR languages and the multicols options does not work correctly.

Comment: @HoseinRahnama what exactly do you mean "does not work correctly"? Multicol only alters the order in which the columns are filled anything else is up to the language package, etc that is used. If you have difficulties I suggest you ask a separate question with an example of what does not work and what you would expect instead.